# Разместить AdView под ScrollView

Tags: android, xml

Есть такая разметка. `ScrollView` заезжает на `AdView`. Подскажите как сделать так, чтобы внизу был `AdView`, а всю остальную часть занимал `ScrollView`?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgBludo"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:src="@drawable/no_image"
                app:riv_border_color="@color/brown"
                app:riv_border_width="2dp"
                app:riv_corner_radius="4dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/background_corners"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textColor="@color/brown"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtIngredients"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/background_corners"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textColor="@color/brown" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtDescription"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/background_corners"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textColor="@color/brown" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужен `android:layout_below`

```
<ScrollView
...  
android:layout_below="@id/adView">
```